# Python WSGI and syslog

Tags: python, logging, wsgi, syslog

I have a python script that is looging to syslog without an issue.  On the same box I have a python script running via apache and WSGI and I can not get it to log to syslog.  The logging configuration is almost identical and here is the section from the WSGI program.

```
formatter=logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s:%(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger('my_log')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler = logging.handlers.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log',facility=logging.handlers.SysLogHandler.LOG_LOCAL1)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

logging.log(level,"%s" % (msg))

Any idea why it wouldn't work from WSGI or how to get this to work properly?  Thanks.

Comment: It's generally bad form to put logging in a wsgi app anywhere besides `environ['wsgi.errors']`.  why do you need this?

Comment: I'd like logs from this app to go to syslog.  How that happens is less important to me.  I'm not very skilled with WSGI.  I will look into wsgi.errors

Answer (score 1):

Does Apache user have access to '/dev/log'?

Why not send it through to Apache error log and then configure Apache to send output to syslog?